# cut out fields that matched a regex from a delimited string

Tags: bash

Example file:

```
35=A|11=ABC|55=AAA|20=DEF
35=B|66=ABC|755=AAA|800=DEF|11=ZZ|55=YYY
35=C|66=ABC|11=CC|755=AAA|800=DEF|55=UUU
35=C|66=ABC|11=XX|755=AAA|800=DEF
```

i want the output to to print like following, with only column 11= and 55= printed. (They are not at fixed location)

```
11=ABC|55=AAA
11=ZZ|55=YYY
11=CC|55=UUU
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your sample output.  Shouldn't it include the line `11=XX`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i~/^(11|55)=/){printf "%s",(f?"|":"")$i;f=1};print""}' file
11=ABC|55=AAA
11=ZZ|55=YYY
11=CC|55=UUU
11=XX
```

To only show lines that have both a `11` field and a `55` field:

```
$ awk -F'|' '/(^|\|)11=/ && /\|55=/{f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i~/^(11|55)=/){printf "%s",(f?"|":"")$i;f=1};print""}' file
11=ABC|55=AAA
11=ZZ|55=YYY
11=CC|55=UUU
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` might be easier here:

```
sed -nr '/(^|\|)11=[^|]*.*\|55=/s~^.*(11=[^|]*).*(\|55=[^|]*).*$~\1\2~p' file
11=ABC|55=AAA
11=ZZ|55=YYY
11=CC|55=UUU
```